# How to navigate to PWA from iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, browser, progressive-web-apps

My app will launch from a PWA with a single button click, which may be accomplished via a universal link.
When I click a button in my app, how do I return to the PWA or the same browser window from which my app was launched?

Comment: iOS 9 onwards, you will find a button on the top left that will redirect you to PWA.

Comment: @AvadheshSharma Thank you, I've seen that, however can we implement that functionality in a custom button inside our app?

Comment: Launching app with custom url scheme is possible(https://useyourloaf.com/blog/launching-ios-apps-with-a-custom-url-scheme/). As there is no API provided for such requirements.

Comment: Is it possible to open the browser with a previously opened tab?